# Every real, skew-symmetric matrix is diagonalisable by a unitary matrix

Tags: diagonalization, unitary-matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

I need to show, that every real, skew-symmetric matrix M can be diagonalized by a unitary matrix U.
$$
M=-M^T \implies M = U D U^\dagger \quad \textrm{with} \quad U U^\dagger = U^\dagger U = \mathbb{I}
$$
I managed to show that $D$ is purely imaginary and that $U^\dagger U$ is a real, symmetric matrix, but i can't quite get to $U^\dagger U = \mathbb{I}$.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2049428/is-a-real-skew-symmetric-matrix-diagonalizable). Since a real skew-symmetric matrix is normal, it is diagonalizable (by a unitary matrix) over $\Bbb C$. Over $\Bbb R$ this need not be true.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I read that post, what I'm struggling with ist not showing, that $M$ is diagonalizable, but that $U$ is unitary. From my understanding, $M$ being diagonalizable just means, that a diagonal matrix $D$ and an invertible matrix $V$ exist with $M=V D V^{-1}$. What i need to show is, that for $M=-M^T$ $V^{-1}=V^\dagger$.

Comment: You know that there exists a basis of orthonormal vectors of $A$. This is equivalent to stating that $A$ is unitarily diagonalizable, with the matrix $Q$ having as columns the orthonormal eigenvectors of $A$.