is the Hamiltonian matrix (mathematics) diagonalizble
Examining the following Hamiltonian matrix:
$H=\begin{bmatrix} A & -BR^{-1}B^{\mathrm{T}} \\ -Q & -A^{\mathrm{T}} \end{bmatrix}$
where the pair $(A,B)$ is controllable, the pair $(A,Q)$ is observable and $Q,R$ are positive definite. All matrices are real.
Is there a way to prove that this Hamiltonian matrix is diagonalizble?
I couldn't find any formal proof or prove it myself.
Thank you for you attention.

See for example the answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2049428/is-a-real-skew-symmetric-matrix-diagonalizable

How do you think adding "(mathematics)" clarifies anything on a mathematics site?

$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 \ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ is a Hamiltonian matrix but is not diagonalizable.

The matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1 & 1 & 0&0\0&1&0&0\0&0&-1&0\0&0&-1&-1}
$$
is another counterexample
